# Run/stop command in terminal without human interference?

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell, command-line, terminal

As a beginner Linux user I'm facing with the little problem. I have 1 command in terminal like in the picture:  [image]

When I run this command it will generate some lines, but the problem is I need to make this command stops after 5 seconds without actually pressing `ctrl + c` by human :

[image: ctrl + c stops command]

What methods I need to use to make this done by computer without actually pressing `ctrl + c` because I need to repeat this process over 1000 times.

- run command
- stop command

  - (pause xx seconds)
- run command
- stop command

  - (pause xx seconds)
- etc.

Do I need to install some special programs or it can be done using bash scripting?

Comment: Don't post images of text please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the command in the background and then sleep for 5 seconds in the foreground and then kill the background command.

- Run the command in the background:

  ```
  command &
  ```
- Save the command PID in a variable:

  ```
  command_pid=$!
  ```
- Sleep for 5 secs:

  ```
  sleep 5
  ```
- Kill the background process:

  ```
  kill "$command_pid"
  ```

Now you can add a pause and put the whole in a loop, etc.

Loop:

```
for ((i=0; i<1000; i++)); do
    crunch 7 7 abcdefghijklm &
    command_pid=$!
    sleep 5
    kill "$command_pid"
    sleep 5 #pause
done
```

Comment: I'm sorry because I don't understand how to use your suggested commands. Do I need to type one by one in terminal and press Enter or this is assumed to be in one executable file or something else? I don't quite understand the concept because of poor knowledge.

Comment: @Vcore9 I added an example. Put it in a file and then do `. file_name`. It will go 1000 times.

Comment: this works but can you suggest me how I can add an option to this loop which simulate keyboard presses, for example: after line `sleep 5` if I press button K and then Enter on keyboard it will show that on screen and press Enter to jump in new line. What should I use to accomplish that?

Comment: @Vcore9 I'm not sure what you want to achieve. Can you give an example?

Comment: I'm trying to do simple automation of some commands that I'm using like crunch and others. Sometimes command prompt asks: "Do you want to continue? [n=NO, Y=yes]", so I need to press y and Enter to continue. Is possible to add this actions inside loop?

Comment: @Vcore9 Some commands have an option like `-y` that assumes yes to all questions. You can also use `yes` with some pipes or redirections. Start a new question for this with details of what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `timeout(1)` is available, the shell command

```
timeout 5s whateverthatcommandis; sleep 99
```

should kill the program after five seconds (assuming the program is well behaved...) and then `sleep` for whatever your xx seconds are. These commands could then be wrapped in some sort of loop as necessary; assuming `seq` is available (on BSD one might instead use `jot`) a typical loop might run along the lines of:

```
for n in `seq 1 1000`; do timeout 5s whateverthatcommandis; sleep 99; done
```

The shell loop, by the way, may be rendered somewhat more legible under ZSH:

```
repeat 1000 { timeout 5s whateverthatcommandis; sleep 99 }
```

Comment: ``for n in `seq 1 1000`; do timeout 5s whateverthatcommandis; sleep 99; done`` only works first time, it stops after 5 seconds, then pause for xx seconds but it don't want to start again, just stays on root@kali:~# and waits something to be typed in. Command `repeat 1000 { timeout 5s whateverthatcommandis; sleep 99 }` didn't work in terminal.